# Get result from JOIN table by checking values in other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, inner-join

I have a 1..n relation between person and orders.
Order can have ACTIVE or CANCELLED status.
One person can have at most one ACTIVE order, but can have inifinite number of CANCELLED orders.
Lets assume that content of my join table looks like this:

[image]

To get persons with ACTIVE order my query is just:

`select * from persons p inner join orders o on p.id = o.person_id where o.status = 'ACTIVE';`

The result should be persons with id 1 and 3. That's simple.

But now, I need to get all those persons which don't have any ACTIVE shipping, so the result of such query should be person with id 2 (does not necessarily have to be distinct row). I can't just change to != 'ACTIVE' in above query, because then I get all those 3 persons, as all of them have orders with status other than ACTIVE.

If I were to explain it by words I'd say that for every row I need to check also other row's with the same p.id and check if ACTIVE status does not occur in any of them.

Any suggestions how can I achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get all those persons which don't have any ACTIVE shipping

You can use `not exists`:

```
select * 
from persons p 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from orders o
    where o.person_id = p.id and o.status = 'ACTIVE'
);
```

For performance with this query, consider an index on `orders(person_id, status)`.

Note that this also allows persons that have no order at all. If you want to avoid that, then use aggregation instead:

```
select p.* 
from persons p 
inner join orders o on o.person_id = p.id
group by p.id
having max(o.status = 'ACTIVE') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select p.*
from persons p inner join
     orders o
     on p.id = o.person_id
group by p.id
having sum(o.status = 'ACTIVE') = 0;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Query works like a charm.